# I can't update Ubuntu 2 months now

Tags: 12.10, updates, update-manager, software-updater

So when running `sudo apt-get update`
i get errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Because of that update manager always popus up message that i should check my internet connection. So what do i do? How do i remove this packages?

Btw the skype problem started from the moment i tried installing skype from USC.. I ended up installing skype by deb file but having this problem from then...

Also my etc/apt/sourced.list.d doesn't have a skype file or a subfolder..

Ubuntu 12.10 here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend first to comment out or remove those 2 PPA which are not part the official repositories and are the ones giving you an error.

First install `ppa-purge` which is in the **proposed** repositories in case you don't see it:

[image]

If you don't have the proposed repositories enabled, you will not be able to do it with the error you have right now, so for the moment you will need to do the following:

1. Open the DASH and type `sources`, it should show you **Software Sources**. Open it and go to the **Other Software** tab. It should look something like the following image:

   [image]
2. Start removing/disabling any PPA you do not need apart from the ones that gave you an error which were:

   http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages

   http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages

   http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages

   http://ppa.launchpad.net/cooperjona/stormcloud/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages

   If you click on any of this links you will get as 404 error which means the source moved to another planet (It is gone!!). So look for this in your **Other Software** tab and remove them. After that remember to activate the **Proposed** repository and simply close Software Sources.
3. Now go to a terminal and: `sudo apt-get update`.

It should work now, if not, look at the error message and remove any following PPA that gives you trouble.

Comment: The problem is that skype and stormcloud are not listed in other software.. i am sure about it...

Comment: I fount the stormcloud thing (http://i.imgur.com/5JbWU.png) and disabled it.. That error fixed.. What about skype now? I want skype installed in my system and also to be able to update my system..

Comment: @Leon-TastyDev - Just disable the PPA for skype and use the Skype found in Software Center. Ubuntu in 12.10 has the latest version of Skype.

Comment: 1) Skype ppa is not listed in the "Other software", 2) ppa-purge ppa:skype gives the error "Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: ppa:skype ppa:skype" , 3) i just removed skype from synaptic, same error when trying to update

Comment: what you left with then is discarding all ppa and start adding each one and testing until you find the one

Comment: You are right. It was canonical ppas.. All ok now :)